# Building Docker Image Using Kaniko tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

Tags: docker, kaniko

I am trying to build a custom alpine docker image using `Kaniko`.
When I attempt to use the `APK` package manager to download package, I see the following ssl error.

```
:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c
```

Note that I am behind an enterprise proxy. I have already provided Kaniko with certificate bundles and proxy settings. That is why I am able to pull alpine images from docker hub.

```
ARG HTTP_PROXY
ARG HTTPS_PROXY

FROM alpine:3.13.2

ENV http_proxy=$HTTP_PROXY
ENV https_proxy=$HTTPS_PROXY

RUN apk update
```

What is the issue with the SSL in this case, and how can I configure the `APK`/Docker to ensure I am able to download packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was not due to configuration. The issue was due to alpine image. There is a bug with 13.3.2.

I reverted my image to `alpine3.12`.